# AngularJs $scope variables are late in initializing when controller loads

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova

I am working on a HTML5 mobile app using AngularJs. The performance is alright on windows phone and Android but on iOS it is creating performance issues on some devices.

The issue is when we switch from one view to another, controller doesn't load on time and hence $scope variables are not initialized. I am using these variables in binding in views, so the element which is supposed to be hidden is visible.

This is happening with elements which are depends on models and manipulations inside controller. It is creating performance issues.

**Edited**
Imp thing: This is not occurring very first time the view loads. When I go back to other view and come back, It starts happening (i.e. No manipulations by controller. No variables gets initialized)

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: can use routing `resolve` to pre-load data. Need more specifics

Comment: Well here there is no warning it gives but when I apply alert at the end of $scope.init() function, the alert comes for 10 times one by one. Also as I edited in Q above, It doesn't happen for the first time when view loads. It occurs then after.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a general question. But there are mainly two things you can do.

1. Resolve the data in the routes to make sure the data is available before the controller is running.
2. Wrap the scope variables in a timeout to make sure the dom is rendered.

Comment: The dom has been rendered but nothing has been manipulated inside controller. The view is visible as it is without any manipulations.
Say $scope.ddlShow is a variable used for showing a drop down list. The drop down list is visible as it is and $scope.ddlShow is not even initialised.

Imp thing: This is not occurring very first time the view loads. When I go back to other view and come back, It starts happening

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are using

```
<div ng-show="isSomeFlag"></div>
<div ng-hide="isSomeFlag"></div>
```

Inside your controller, you are using

```
$scope.isSomeFlag= true;
```

Add the following:

```
<div ng-show="isLoading && isSomeFlag"></div>
<div ng-hide="isLoading && isSomeFlag"></div>
```

And in the controller on the last line set the isLoading flag to true.

```
$scope.isSomeFlag = true;
...
$scope.isLoading = true; // controller ends here (below)
```

In this way the elements will behave as expected. However, there are many other ways, for eg, resolving etc, but this should solve your UI update issue.